# How to construct begin and end iterators in the middle of an array?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, reverse

I am trying to reverse a part of an array in place using std::reverse which takes two iterators. When I try to construct the iterators as follows:

```
int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
reverse(begin(a + 2), end(a + 4));
```

I get an error:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:33: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::valarray<_Tp>’ and ‘int*’ reverse(begin(a + 2), end(a + 4));
```

What's the correct way to construct the iterators?

Comment: I think I found a way to reverse the elements, I just have to do reverse(a+2, a+4);

Comment: But I am still curious about how to make the error go away.

Comment: You said yourself how to make it go away - get rid of the `begin` and `end` calls which are wrong and shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miles is right.

But, if you wanted iterators for some other reason (say, it won't always be an array), you *can* do that.

You just have to increment the iterator, rather than the array you construct it from:

```
reverse(begin(a) + 2, begin(a) + 4);
```

(You also wrote `end` when I think you meant `begin`!)

Comment: I think he meant "end", as in "I want the end iterator to point at a+4". In this case the code should be `begin`, but `end(a) - 3` would also work.

Comment: @Pete Hmm I see yeah they could have thought "begin" and "end" were argument decorators like some languages have, rather than func calls

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The question gives a very strong impression that OP thought these were constructor calls, making one instance of `class begin` and another of `class end`

Comment: @Ben Regardless of the internal workings of the OP's mind, they're not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You and I know that, but unlike "argument decorators", class constructors do exist in C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not really sure what the purpose of this line of discussion is? Are we really arguing over what the OP didn't think the language feature wasn't?  Why?

Comment: @Aditya `std::begin(a)` gives you an iterator to the start of `a`, which you can then treat like any other iterator*, including adding stuff to it (* not every iterator supports random access like that, but close enough for now)

Answer (score 5):

`std::begin` and `std::end` are functions that accept a container and give you iterators pointing to the first and one-past-the-end elements, respectively.

`std::begin` and `std::end` are not themselves iterators, and they don't work on raw pointers since pointers don't have any size information.  When you call `std::begin(a+2)`, `a` decays into a pointer to its first element and is shifted 2 elements.  The resulting pointer is passed to `std::begin`, but `std::begin` doesn't work on pointers, so the result is a compilation failure.

To solve your problem, just get rid of the calls to `std::begin` and `std::end`:

```
std::reverse(a+2, a+4);
```

This works since pointers fulfil all of the requirements for an iterator, so the pointers resulting from `a+2` and `a+4` are completely valid to pass to `std::reverse`.

Comment: What's a container? Is it like an interface in Java? Does it mean that everything that is a container has a field called size?

Comment: @Aditya More or less yes. They're not implemented with OOO interfaces like in Java, but they have common names for things so you can treat them that way in templates.

Comment: [Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) is a concept.  Similar to a java interface, but without the inheritance relationship.